# Make a radio button selected when an item select from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. I have the country field in the list and the currency field in the radio button. what I want is, when I will select a country, it will automatically select the currency from the radio button. I have 3 currencies US, EUR & GBP, for EU it will be EUR, for UK it will be GBP & for the rest it will be USD.

please help me....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Radio button and List Check</title></head>
    <body>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="country">
                        <option value="">Please select Country</option>
                        <option value="US">US</option>
                        <option value="EU">EU</option>
                        <option value="UK">UK</option>
                        <option value="China">China</option>
                        <option value="India">India</option>
                        <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
                        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Currency</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio" >USD</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio">EUR</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="optradio">GBP</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>                 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is all HTML. Have you tried actually writing any JS yet?

Comment: are radios ordered accordingly to options??

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
//This solution requires you to order currencies accordingly to countries

   var country = document.getElementById("country");
    var radios = document.querySelectorAll("[name='optradio']");
       country.onchange = function(){
           var si = this.selectedIndex;

           for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
              radios[i].checked = (si === i);
             }
      }
```